# When is  MSDTC required?

Tags: .net, oracle11g, msdtc

I have one oracle server which is installed on DBServer1. I have a Web Server WebServer1 that connects to DBServer1. The DBServer1 has two schemas Schema1 and Schema2.

On WebServer1, I have a ParentComponent, Child1Component and Child2Component. Child1Component connects to Schema1 and Child2Component Connects to Schema2. All these components are .NET DLL components. Each component implements its own connection string. ParentComponent opens a transaction and makes calls to Child1Component and Child2Component for some write operations.

In this scenario will the WebServer1 switch to MSDTC?

(My Understanding is that MSDTC comes into the picture only when the DBservers are physically different and these two servers are accessed from the same transaction. )

Comment: Distributed transaction add complexity. You could avoid this complexity if both components share the same database connection. After all, there's just a single database instance. With synonyms and grants, you should be able to create an environment in Oracle where both components can share the same login so you don't need to change either component except for the connections string.

Comment: I am still not clear whether MSDTC will be used automatically in this scenario. i.e if there are two servers, will MSDTC will be used by default?